# How to fit weekday only data into ts() function to forecast using Arima

Tags: time-series

I searched everywhere but I can't find any question or documentation on this issue. I know that ts() automatically creates a time series based on your start date and frequency but I'm unable to find what to do when the data consists of only weekdays?

Comment: Stock prices would be an example of this, since major exchanges are only open Monday through Friday.  Usually you would ignore the missing days and assume Monday follows Friday.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. So would you add NA values in the data for weekends or would you alter the frequency in the ts() function?

Comment: alter the frequency